# Dynamic Multidimensional Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, new-operator

The program should take a dimension n and make a multidimensional array of nxn dimensions, I know it has to be done with the *new[ ]* operator, thus it should be done using pointers, I found a lot of ways on the internet but I´m new to this topic and couldn't understand well how they work, here is one of those codes I found that claims to work:

```
main()
{
    double n;
    cout<<"Enter the n dimension to the matrix[nxn]: ";
    cin>>n;
    matrix=new int*[n];
    int *data=new int[n*n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      matrix[i]=&data[i*n];
}
```

My question is: is this code right? if so, how does it Works? else, wich code does Works? (if you could and a Little explanation I'd apreciate it)

Comment: _"I know it has to be done with the new[ ] operator"_ No. The idiomatic way is `std::vector<std::vector<int> matrix(n,std::vector<int>(n));`. And no, the code you found doesn't work.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ EDIT: you missed an `>` after first `int`. Did not notice that and I got compile errors

Comment: @Fureeish [Small typo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc3ea6758d5212ec), fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use raw pointers, better use `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin << n;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(n, std::vector<int>(n));
    // Do whatever with matrix

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, just a Little question, how do I should I handle this matrix? as any other multidimensional array matrix[a][b] or does it has to be in a diferent way?

Comment: Yes, you can handle it just like any other multidimensional array: `matrix[a][b]`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way with dynamic allocation would be this (if only arrays are involved) :

```
matrix = new int*[n];        //create an array of 'n' pointers
for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    matrix[i] = new int[n];  //allocate memory equivalent of 'n' ints to each of the 'n' pointers
```

Comment: You should complete your code with the appropriate deallocations.